# How can I listenTo a NestedModel change on it's collection?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm using **[NestedModel](https://github.com/afeld/backbone-nested)** change plugin to support nested model changes into my models.

I tried this into my View where I got a reference to a collection.

```
....
initialize: function(){
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', foo);
},
foo: function(model){
   console.log("Some model changed")
}
```

By doing FooModel.set({"fooPropertie.BarPropertie": "fooBarValue"});
I would expect to trigger a collection change event.
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I did a JS Fiddle that answers my own question. First conclusion: 1. It's possible to listen for changes on a collection of Backbone.NesteModel models.
2. Change event fires pretty well on collections...even if we are setting nested properties as you can see on my JSFIDDLE below. http://goo.gl/FXuV8B

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to define the trouble since you do not provide the way `this.collection` was defined. But I see at least one thing to tune: `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.foo);`. Add `this.` before `foo` call. Currently in your context `foo` is `undefined`.